# How to make a video to stream on specified quality in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to stream a video. But how to make the server code to send the video at specific quality?

Comment: What kind of Stream (WebRTC or Netflix style "Stream") - also is there a specific resolution you want or is it per request?

Comment: as per request similar to has youtube provides

Comment: Then I would suggest using something like [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) while also saving multiple versions with differing resolutions since video editing can become quite CPU/Memory intensive and sometimes blocking